# jquery serialize not serializing inputs in a hidden div

Tags: jquery

I am using serizlse on a form. I have a hidden div inside the form and I need to grab the inouts inside if that div.

```
<form>
<div style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="one" value="one">
</div>

<div>
<input type="text" name="two" value="two">
</div>
</form>
```

When I view my post data I can see the value of two but not the value of one.
Is their a way to use serialize on inputs inside of a hidden div?

Comment: you need to give us your javascript code

Comment: You sure the input is not **disabled**?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me...

```
<form>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="one" value="one" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="two" value="two" />
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  alert($('form').serialize());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

All fields within the form will be serialized regardless of their display.

Example w/ your form:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8gaY/2/